# Reference error : epson node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js, i have a requirement of calling epson api's. Which works fine when used with javascript, outside node.js. The code is simple, just call the js file of there's and create a object and build the data out of it. There is no other dependency required.

```
Ex : 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/epos-print-3.0.0.js"></script>
    var builder = new epson.ePOSBuilder();
```

Doing above works fine in general like calling those js file and using.

So, for the same in node.js, i added the js file and **i see the js file being included in the page** but still i get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: epson is not defined
    at printReceipt (cart:729:21)
    at cart:329:13
    at cart:693:9
    at Request._callback (cart:716:5)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/admin1/git/presentation/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/admin1/git/presentation/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
.
.
.
```

Is there any specific way of creating a 3rd party api object in node.js ??.

Any help, appreciated !!!

Comment: What do you mean with "I see the js file being included in the page"? If you're trying to make that lib work in node you should not be having a page where that gets included, not in a normal workflow at least, could you expand on that please?

Comment: Node.js runs on the _server_ side right? Why is it important then to mention that the other script is loaded on the _client_?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni What i meant was, i can see the JS file being loaded through firebug. As i can create an object with the help of that js file.

Comment: Ah ok, you're saying that the lib does work in the browser. How are you including it in your project? Could you show us that part of your code?

Comment: you mean the js file ?? or the object creation ??

Comment: app.get('/epos-print-3.0.0.js', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/epos-print-3.0.0.js');
  }); ------------------- js file inclusion in app.js

Comment: this code only sends the file to the client.
If you want to use it in nodejs you need to require inside of your application code.

Comment: there is a page.js file which has the <head> tag definitions as module.exports ....  i have included there as well. Is it what u meant OR any other ??

Comment: Do you want to use the library server side? Then check this link:
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules
Otherwise please provide more details on what you try to achieve.

Comment: Ok, my lib js file is in root. And in my js file i did like this. var epson = require('/the js file'); and i get as TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Yes, i want it on server side.

Comment: You have an error in the path, it should be `var epson = require('./your-library');`, notice the dot

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Yes, i added its still the same. Check this, var epson = require('./epos-print-3.0.0.js'); var builder = new epson.ePOSBuilder(); and that js is in same directory.... Tried placing in root directory as well

Comment: The problem could be that your library is not being exported to be used by node's commonjs module structure, if you don't find a `module.exports` into it then there's a good chance. If that's the case open a new question seeking help for this.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have it, Its an independent file. It runs without node as well...

Comment: Here is the link to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714632/module-exports-inclusion-library-file

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni i have added a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714632/module-exports-inclusion-library-file