# Module exports inclusion - Library file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an external library which needs to be integrated in node.js. I tried the following

In my js file, i have included the library as

```
var epson = require('./epos-print.js');
```

and i tried creating the object as

```
var builder = new epson.ePOSBuilder();
```

which is in my current directory. I get the error as `"module not found"`. Which means i am failing in first step itself. Is there any other settings required to create an object of my library file.

My library file has like this

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    function ePOSBuilder() {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }
.
.
.
.
.

})(window);
```

Tried following ways in the library file.

```
exports.ePOSBuilder = function ePOSBuilder() {

}
```

AND

```
module.exports = exports = function ePOSBuilder() {
}
```

AND

```
tried with permission 775 as well.
```

Still it says. Module not found.

Comment: Do you have a sibling-file named `epos-print.js`? Does it export `ePOSBuilder`? How does you file structure look?

Comment: Can you post the exact error as well? I believe node throws "Error: Cannot find module" and the path if a require statement fails.

Comment: Yes i have a sibling file. It doesn't have anything with export. Its a library file which works outside node and i need to integrate in node now.

Comment: @PherricOxide here is the error Error: Module ./epos-print.js not found.

Comment: That's usually a path problem then. Are you sure the file is named properly and really is in the same folder as the one you're running node on?

Comment: Also, if Linux try checking the file permissions to make sure node can access it with whatever user it's running as.

Comment: Yes, i am cent percent sure.

Comment: app.js and other files has 664