# Call JS through cURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I am trying to call my js file through cURL. That JS file in-turn call's third party API to fetch me the result.

**Overview of JS file.**

In js file i am creating an object of the 3rd party library file and sending them the relevant data to get the response back. This response need to be captured and returned back when call'd through cURL.

**Procedure of calling cURL**

The cURL function will be triggered as an API call.

**What i have tried so far !**

I am storing the response of the library file in a cookie. So that i can use the same. I am able to achieve this through browser. But, when tried with REST client, i get all my `<script>` function as response also it doesn't call the library file too.

So, how can i call the JS file through cURL OR is there any other alternative way to achieve this. ?

NOTE : It is not a regular browser flow, it has to be a API call.

Please let me know on this !

Comment: I don't think you can "call (client-side) JS" through cURL. Even Google can not do this until a few years ago. Why don't you simply use cURL to communicate with the third party API?

Comment: The problem with the third part API is, i need to create an object of that API and build the data in JS itself as the methods are defined in that library.

Comment: I guess the data being transferred is still in plain text, so you can still do it in cURL directly.

Comment: Ok, let me give a try. Thanks

Comment: curl will not evaluate client side javascript. You could try to migrate your javascript code and library to node.js.

Comment: i also tried including the library in node.js. I get "module not found error" This was the reason for me to switch from node and achieve it through an API. Please check my previous question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714632/module-exports-inclusion-library-file?noredirect=1#comment27575622_18714632